# rational roots for $5x^7+3x^2-4 =0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all possible rational roots for  $5x^7+3x^2-4 =0$

So the problem only looks for rational roots, that eliminates a lot of cases. But I cannot find a way to factorize this polynomial or find a special case solution to move forward...

Comment: Use the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the rational root theorem (which is basically plugin in an irreducible fraction $\frac pq$ and checking what are the possibilities for $p, q$ based on divisibility), all the pairs of coprime integers $(p,q)$ with $\frac pq$ being a root of the polynomial have the properties $p\mid\,-4$ and $q\mid 5$. Thus all the possible roots are in the set $\{\pm 1, \pm \frac 15, \pm 2, \pm \frac 25, \pm 4, \pm \frac 45\}$. Now it’s a matter of computational power to test all of all of these... *but if you want it a bit smarter,*

Note that if a root is integer, since $(5x^5+3)x^2 = 4,\ x^2 \mid 4 \implies |x|\in\{1,2\}$. If $x = \pm 2,\ 5x^5 = -2$, with no rational solutions. Testing $\pm 1$ we still have no solutions. So there are no integral solutions. For the remaining ones, $q = 5$; so, multiplying by $5^6$, $\frac pq$ satisfies the polynomial iff $p^7 + 5^4p^2 - 4\cdot5^6 = 0$. Again, $p^2 \mid 2^25^6$; so $p \mid 2\cdot5^2$. Since by hypothesis $\operatorname{gcd}(p,5) = 1$, $p$ is either $\pm 1$ or $\pm 2$. It’s not hard to see that $\pm 1$ does not solve the problem.  For $\pm2$, we need $\pm 2^5 + 5^4 = 5^6$ which is clearly untrue since $\mathrm{even} + \mathrm{odd} \neq \mathrm{odd}$.

No rational solutions for us!

Comment: We do not need to compute the full polynomial expression for any of these roots except the very simple cases $\pm 1$.  Unfortunately the problem is tagged contest-math and is recently asked so I cannot give a full answer.  Hoping the OP will let us know when the contest is over.

Comment: It looks that the polynomial is irreducible. I was thinking about the splitting field, but as a contest math problem, it seems the most standard way to solve it

Comment: @OscarLanzi this is just a practice problem, not a problem from a real contest. if you have better solution than this one, I am happy to see!

Comment: This looks good enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments here us my answer.

As noted by Lucas the Rational Root Theorem guarantees that any rational root must be in this set:

$\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 4,\pm\frac15,\pm\frac25,\pm\frac45\}$

We may now eliminate some of these candidates.

If $|x|\ge 2$ then $|5x^7|\ge 640$ is so large that the combined absolute values of the other terms cannot match it.  Thus the overwhelming or **dominant** term $5x^7$ prevents $x\in\{\pm2,\pm4\}$ from possibly being a root.

If $x$ is one of the fractional values above then $3x^2$ and $4$ are multiples of $1/25$ but $5x^7$ is instead a non-multiple of $5$ divided by $5^6$.  So the overall sum is stuck between multiples of $1/25$ and can't be zero for any of these $x$ values.  If you are familiar with $p$-adics, you can say that again $5x^7$ is dominant, this time in the $5$-adic norm.

We are left with $\pm 1$ but these fail by simple computations.

Leaving **no rational roots.**